# The 'is' operator is not working on objects with the same identity

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, cpython

I'm running:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct  6 2017, 09:25:50)
GCC 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14) on Linux 2
```

As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for *object identity*: `x is y` is `True` if and only if `x` and `y` are the *same object*.

To get an object's *identity*, we can use the [`id` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id).

---

If we open up a new REPL we can see that `300` and `-6` have the same identity (on [CPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython), this means that both refer to the same memory address):

```
>>> id(300)
94766593705400
>>> id(-6)
94766593705400
```

Note that the actual values may differ from execution to execution, but they are always equal.

However, doing `300 is -6` yields `False`:

```
>>> 300 is -6
False
```

I have a couple of questions:

- Why (*and how*) do `300` and `-6` share the same identity?
- If they do, why is `300 is -6` yielding `False`?

Comment: REPL reuses `IDs`. Try this and you'll understand: `print(id(300)) or print(id(-6)) or 300 is -6`

Comment: Can't reproduce in Python 3 on Windows `Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> id(300)
7807344
>>> id(-6)
8757184
>>> id(300)
8757184
>>> id(-6)
8755376`

Comment: However, it reproduces in Python 2 on Centos `Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:34:23)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> id(300)
15912616
>>> id(-6)
15912616
>>> id(300)
15912616`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Do you have any source to back that up, by chance?

Comment: It's actually mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#id)... "Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value."

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks! Now it makes sense

Comment: It's also worth noting that Python caches inetegers in the range [-5, 256]: `>>> 6 is 6
True
>>> -999 is -999
False`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After `id(300)` is executed, no more references to `300` exist, so the id is freed. When you execute `id(6)`, it gets that same chunk of memory and stores 6 instead. When you do `-300 is 6`, `-300` and `6` are both referenced at the same time, so they won't have the same address anymore.

If you keep references to both `-300` and `6`, this happens:

```
>>> a, b = -300, 6
>>> id(a)
some number
>>> id(b)
some different number; 6 is still in the other memory address.
```

Note: In CPython, numbers from -5 to 256 (I think) are cached, and will always have the same address, so this will not happen.

Comment: I've just verified what you said. This makes complete sense

Comment: I'd use another example than 6 since it is in the range of integers that Python caches anyway (-5 to 256): `>>> 6 is 6
True
>>> -999 is -999
False`

Comment: @DeepSpace Nice catch! Editing.

Answer (score 8):

This is documented behavior of the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#id) function:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long
>   integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object
>   during its lifetime. **Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may
>   have the same `id()` value.**

The lifetime of an integer object in the sample code is just the function call (e.g. `id(300)`) as no other references to it exist.

Comment: I couldn't understand that statement at the time but now I do!